# Google Sheets API v4 service_account - forbidden: The caller does not have permission (Google::Apis::ClientError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-ruby-client

**Ruby: 2.3.1**

**Rails: 5.0.0**

I need to access and update my private Google Sheet through Google Sheets API.
Eventually this shall be done by a recurring background job in my Rails application. Hence I have setup a service account in my Google Cloud Console.

But to start playing with Google Sheets API I have created a script:

```
require 'google/apis/sheets_v4'

ENV["GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE"] = 'service_account'
ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL"] = '<client_email_from_downloaded_json_here>'
ENV["GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY"] = "<private_key_from_downloaded_json_here>"

SCOPE = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::AUTH_SPREADSHEETS

authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(SCOPE)

# Initialize the API
service = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::SheetsService.new
service.authorization = authorization

spreadsheet_id = '<MY SPREADSHEET ID HERE>'

sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

range = "#{sheet_name}!A2:B"

response = service.get_spreadsheet_values(spreadsheet_id, range)

puts 'No data found.' if response.values.empty?

response.values.each do |row|
  # Print columns A and B, which correspond to indices 0 and 1.
  puts "#{row[0]}, #{row[1]}"
end
```

When I run that script

```
$ rails runner -e development lib/scripts/google_sheets_api_demo.rb
/home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/google-api-client-0.9.12/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:211:in `check_status': forbidden: The caller does not have permission (Google::Apis::ClientError)
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/google-api-client-0.9.12/lib/google/apis/core/api_command.rb:102:in `check_status'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/google-api-client-0.9.12/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:179:in `process_response'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/google-api-client-0.9.12/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:286:in `execute_once'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/google-api-client-0.9.12/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:107:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:54:in `block in retriable'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `times'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `retriable'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/google-api-client-0.9.12/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:104:in `block in execute'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:54:in `block in retriable'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `times'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/retriable-2.1.0/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `retriable'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/google-api-client-0.9.12/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:96:in `execute'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/google-api-client-0.9.12/lib/google/apis/core/base_service.rb:346:in `execute_or_queue_command'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/google-api-client-0.9.12/generated/google/apis/sheets_v4/service.rb:322:in `get_spreadsheet_values'
  from lib/scripts/google_sheets_api_demo.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:60:in `load'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:60:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in `require'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in `require_command!'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:104:in `runner'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
  from /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@my_integrations/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:9:in `require'
  from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

If I try to access a public sheet it works. I have tried a lot but unable to figure out what is causing this. Initially I used API Key approach for authorization but as per the documentation found at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/auth/api-keys it says

> When calling APIs that do not access private user data, you can use
>   simple API keys. These keys are used to authenticate your application
>   for accounting purposes. The Google Developers Console documentation
>   also describes API keys.
>
> Note: If you do need to access private user data, you must use OAuth
>   2.0. See Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications, Using OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications, and Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server
>   Applications for more information.

Hence I switched to Service Account approach. But it didn't helped.

Can anybody please let me know what is it I am missing?

Additional Findings:

The following post https://stackoverflow.com/a/38530755/936494 looks helpful but as per my requirement I want to avoid 3-Legged oauth the reason being the sheet is supposed to be accessed and updated through a background-job.

Answer (score 7):

This is resolved. Thanks to [Steve Bazyl (Google member)](https://github.com/sqrrrl) who provided the following valuable suggestion which straight-away resolved the problem:

> Did you share the sheet with the service account? Service accounts are effectively separate users and need to be on the ACLs the same as any other user.

Reference: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/461#issuecomment-243328234