# Google Sheets - "The caller does not have permission" exception

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am using v4 and `google/apiclient:2.9.1` (php).

I successfully access the spreadsheet through oauth2. It is meaning I can read and edit data. But sometimes I get 403  http code with a body

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

for no apparent reason. I don't change the permissions of spreadsheet, don't revoke permissions, etc. Re-access request is successful and the data becomes available again through API.

Why it happens? How do I get rid of the need to re-request access permissions?

This is repeated on different accounts and spreadsheets.

Comment: Try the solution for the similar issue here and see if it works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529162/how-to-debug-the-caller-does-not-have-permission

Comment: There is a handler edit in `\Google\AuthHandler\Guzzle6AuthHandler::attachToken`. I was getting  `\GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface` from container and therefore I was getting this error. Thus, guzzle client who had a state was obtained from container.